# unable to run any angular project after changing angular version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, node-modules, npm-publish

My project was running completely ok , but today due to some other projects i did had to change the angular version , due to compatibility issues , but anyhow i was able to change versions using nvm use but after i could'nt build my any angular projects . this is the error i get when i run the command

> ng serve

```
$ ng serve 
bash: ng: command not found
```

> node version

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Standard User\Desktop\demo\DatingApp\client\version'
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I've seen that this issue i'm faceing is very popular and faced by so many peoples , i'm very new to angular,so i find difficulty in versioning . bcz angular has so many versions and i've tried many aprroaches to solve this error which was mentioned already here and github.

Comment: Maybe `ng` got uninstalled or otherwise bumped from your `PATH`, but an `npm install -g ng` or equivalent with `yarn` if you prefer should fix that. `which ng` should show where it got installed.

Comment: @tadman , it did'nt fixed it . can you please , suggest anything else .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to clean the cache from run this command below:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then after you need to re install the Angular from this command below:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: thx @Abishek , is it necessary to clear cache every time , when we change version .

Comment: @PrinceBhati, not always necessary to clear cache, but sometimes this problem comes then then its necessary to do clear cache.